# Can I get refractive eye surgery and pass a medical in Europe fitting EASA requirements?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical, airline-pilot

I would like to attend a Class I pilot Licence, but my eyes are not 'the best'. If I'd undergo refractive surgery (RS from now on), and the intervention goes well, will I fit the requirements?

For example, your defect can't be more than -5 of miopy per eye before the RS.

My question mainly refers to the eligibility requirements in Europe, they seem not matching with Italian ones.

this is the abstract.
“Applicants who have had refractive surgery and are being considered for
medical certification (first time?) or recertification (this should be the second visit on) should meet the following criteria:
a) The surgery is uncomplicated.
b) Vision is stable.
c) There is no corneal haze and no complaints of glare, halos or “ghosting”.
d) The result meets the visual requirements of Annex 1, and the assessment
must be based on measurements made by a qualified vision care specialist
acceptable to the Licensing Authority.
e) There should be follow-up examinations by a qualified vision care specialist
six months after return to duty and yearly thereafter.”

If i can skip the limit of eye sight taking a licence out of Italy (for ex.in other European countries,the US, etc) will I be able to pass the EASA medical visit as a pilot qualified in the States and be able to choose where to work?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Answering this question for "all over the world" is pretty much impossible: You will need to narrow the scope to the *one specific jurisdiction* you are looking to train in. Every nation has its own regulatory structure, and its own medical requirements. Many allow you to get a pilot's license after refractive surgery, or using corrective lenses ([the FAA permits it, for example](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/exam_tech/et/31-34/rp/). Some may not.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This question is much too broad to be answered, because a complete answer would have to include every country in the world.  Please edit the question to include a specific jurisdiction (if you are interested in a few, please post them as different questions) and we will be able to help you out.  I would suggest that you ask it for the country in which you will apply for the medical, or for ICAO requirements, as they would be the most appropriate.

Comment: voretaq7 and Lnafziger, first of all thank you for your answers.
My question was made to understand what happens 
IF i match the requirements, for example, in the US by FAA, and get the class 1 eligibility. So could I attend the training course there and become a commercial pilot, and then, as a question, move to a company of another country?

Comment: CASA (Australia): [Designated Aviation Medical Examiner's Handbook](http://www.oaansw.com.au/visionstds/CASA_Handbook_Vision_Section.pdf) /// US: [Dear Capt Lim](http://www.askcaptainlim.com/eyesight-pilot-73/854-what-are-the-eyesight-requirements-for-airline-pilots-.html)

Comment: I edited the question to focus on the EASA and Italy requirements. Feel free to improve or roll back the edits if this doesn't match your question well.

Comment: WOW in Australia even Monocular pilots are allowed in some cases o.o

Comment: @Yoda Generally speaking, medical certification does NOT transfer between jurisdictions, unlike the licence itself.

Comment: Ben the thing is: i get the licence in the States, then to convalidate it with EASA they ll surely check if i had or not refractive surgery. So won t I fit their requirements?

Comment: I find your question a bit unclear. You asked if you can get a Class 1 EASA medical after RS, but you also answered that yourself with the quote you gave. And I don't understand the final part about getting an EASA medical as a US pilot? If you aren't sure how to ask your question then you could join the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) and ask for some help there.

Comment: Hi Pondlife, the question -and answers- might look unclear because they were edited few times. I found my answers,not in Easa website but in the different countries' regulations. The UK,for example allow you to have done eye surgery and then to pass the visit. My question about US was made to understand the validations all over the world.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes,

Please consult with the FAA or your governing body on flight physical requirements as well as your eye care provider about approved corrective surgeries as well as limitations.  It does take a little paperwork but should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Carlo, I am in front of the pc searching as hell, and I think you answered properly to my question.
I think your answer was like 'becoming a pilot 'all over the world' is now possible with eye surgery'.
I'll search deeply for my answers and if I find something I'll post the results here.